# Swift Generics: Conforming to protocol by constraining generic parameters to variable types defined by said protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

In my Domain module I am defining a protocol Assignment, TimeLog and AssignmentTimeLog.

When defining a concrete implementation I want to use generics to  conform to the AssignmentTimeLog protocol. To do so I am constraining my generic A, T parameters to be of type Domain.Assignment and Domain.TimeLog. Why does this not satisfy the protocol requirements? I want to understand the logic of what's going on.

```
// Domain Module
public protocol AssignmentTimeLog {

    var assignment: Assignment { get }
    var timeLog: TimeLog { get }
}

// My attempt to create an implementation trows an error
// Error: 
// Type 'AssignmentTimeLog<A, T>' does not conform to protocol 'AssignmentTimeLog'

import Domain

struct AssignmentTimeLog<A, T>: 
    Domain.AssignmentTimeLog where A: Domain.Assignment, T: Domain.TimeLog {
    
    var assignment: A
    var timeLog: T
 
}
```

For Context: The reason for using generics is that later I want to define an extension on AssignmentTimeLog where A & T also implement another protocol. This provides additional functionality without additional code. Concrete types implement the Domain protocols as well as those additional protocols.

I have tried to figure out this by reading the documentation and multiple blogs. But I can't seem to zone in on the exact issue/gap in understanding that I have.

Comment: What do you need the `AssignmentTimeLog` protocol for? Just having a `AssignmentTimeLog<A, T>` struct is enough, no?

Comment: That relates to the architecture I am using. MVVM where the VMs and Views only have access to the protocols defined in the Domain module. Concrete implementation is in a separate module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol says a different thing from what your implementation says.

## Fact 1

According to the protocol this getter

```
var assignment: Assignment { get }
```

can return any value conforming to `Assignment`.

## Fact 2

On the other hand your implementation here

```
var assignment: A
```

says that `assignment` will contain a value of a specific type `A` (which happens to conform to `Assignment`).

These are 2 very different statements.

## The fix

Here's an easy fix

```
protocol AssignmentTimeLog {
    
    associatedtype A: Assignment
    associatedtype B: TimeLog
    
    var assignment: A { get }
    var timeLog: B { get }
}


struct MyAssignmentTimeLog<A, T>: AssignmentTimeLog where A: Assignment, T: TimeLog {
    
    var assignment: A
    var timeLog: T
 
}
```

Comment: I guess I am failing to see the distinction between does 2 statements. You are saying that A happens to conform to Assignment. But isn't the fact that I'm constraining A and T to be of a specific type mean that any instance of the struct must have these properties of said type? ... "A" can be anything that conforms to this type... With regards to the fix I actually tried that an it worked indeed except I can't use the protocol as a type (until the next version of 
Swift comes out)